# Can't assign values into array through for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to return a new array from another array by rounding the value near to 5  and it shouldn't round if the rounded number is less then 40.
but it is showing "IndexError: list assignment index out of range" error .

```
import os
import sys

#
# Complete the gradingStudents function below.
#
def gradingStudents(grades):
    def round_to_next5(n):
        return n + (5 - n) % 5
    j = len(grades)
    r = [j]
    for i in range(0,len(grades)):
        roundi = round_to_next5(grades[i])
        dif = roundi - grades[i]
        if dif < 3 and roundi > 40:
            r[i] = roundi
            print("working1")
        else:
            r[i] = grades[i]
            print("working2")
    return r
if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    n = int(input())

    grades = []

    for _ in range(n):
        grades_item = int(input())
        grades.append(grades_item)

    result = gradingStudents(grades)

    f.write('\n'.join(map(str, result)))
    f.write('\n')

    f.close()
```

Expected an array but it's showing an error.

Comment: Change `r = [j]` to `r = [None] * j`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.
`r = [j]` is culprit of error. I have used numpy to create a `zeros` array and if you do not have numpy install it by the following command `pip install numpy`

Full working code is given below.

```py
    import os
    import sys
    from numpy import zeros
    #
    # Complete the gradingStudents function below.
    #
    def gradingStudents(grades):
        def round_to_next5(n):
            return n + (5 - n) % 5
        j = len(grades)
        r = zeros(j)
        for i in range(0,len(grades)):
            roundi = round_to_next5(grades[i])
            dif = roundi - grades[i]
            if dif < 3 and roundi > 40:
                r[i] = roundi
                print("working1")
            else:
                r[i] = grades[i]
                print("working2, i: ", i)
        return r
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        f = open('text.txt', 'w')

        n = int(input())
        print('Got user input')
        grades = []

        for _ in range(n):
            grades_item = int(input())
            grades.append(grades_item)

        print('Len of grades is: ', len(grades))
        result = gradingStudents(grades)

        f.write('\n'.join(map(str, result)))
        f.write('\n')

        f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of your `IndexError` is at one of the assignments to `r[i]`.  This will cause this error whenever the length of `grades` is greater than one.  The problem is that `r` is initialised to be a list containing a *single* number (the length of grades).

I think you intended to initialise `r` to be a list of length `j`, not containing `j`, for example:

```py
r = [0 for _ in range(j)]
```